# How can I find out if a dynamic component is being displayed or not on the screen and access its properties in Angular8

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a list of users and for each user that is selected a chat box is displayed. Each box is a dynamic component. The idea is that if any of these boxes is being displayed (that is, that instance of the component is active) if a message is written to that user, the data in that box is updated. The messages and user IDs arrive through a socket and I get them in the OnInit () function. Basically what I need is to ask if that chat box (that component) is active or not, in that case I would call a service that returns all user messages and update that component visually (I do this when the logged-in user selects any user in the list through the onClickAdd function). How could I know when receiving the data if the component is activated or not?Here is my code.

App.component.ts

```
import { Component,ViewChild,ViewContainerRef,ComponentFactoryResolver,ComponentRef,OnDestroy,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable,Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ConversacionComponent} from "./components/conversacion/conversacion.component";
import {ChatService} from "./services/chat.service";
import {Global} from "./services/global";
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    providers:[ChatService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy,OnInit {

    @ViewChild('componentsContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: false }) container: ViewContainerRef;
    private subs: Subscription[] = []; 

    public personas:Array<any>;
    public alreadyDone : number[];
    public url_base_perfil=Global.url_base_perfil;
    public url_foto_perfil_default=Global.url_foto_perfil_default;

    public socket:any;
    public uric="ws://localhost:4444";
    constructor( private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,private  _chatService:ChatService) {
        this.alreadyDone=[];

        this.socket = io(this.uric);
        this._chatService.getEjecutivos(1).subscribe(
            response=>{
                if(response.ejecutivos){
                    this.personas=response.ejecutivos;
                }
            },
            error=>{
                console.log(error);
            }
        );



    }

    ngOnDestroy() {

        this.subs.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe());

    }
        ngOnInit(){
            this.socket.on('message',  (msg) =>{            
             this.mandar_mensaje(msg);
            });

        }
    onClickAdd = (elemento) => {

        if(this.alreadyDone.findIndex(x => x === elemento.id) === -1)
        {
            this.alreadyDone.push(elemento.id);
            let nombre_ejecutivo = elemento.getAttribute('data-nombre');
            let foto_persona_destino = elemento.getAttribute('data-foto_perfil');
            this._chatService.getMessages(1,elemento.id).subscribe(
                response=>{
                    if(response.mensajes){    
                        const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ConversacionComponent);
                        const component = this.container.createComponent(factory);
                        component.instance.id_persona_destino= elemento.id;
                        component.instance.nombre_persona_destino= nombre_ejecutivo;
                        component.instance.foto_persona_destino= foto_persona_destino;
                        component.instance.numberCreated = this.container.length;
                        component.instance.mensajes = response.mensajes;
                        // subscribe to component event to know when to delete
                        const selfDeleteSub = component.instance.deleteSelf
                            .pipe(tap(x => {
                                this.alreadyDone = this.alreadyDone.filter(done => done != x);
                                component.destroy();}))
                            .subscribe();


                        // add subscription to array for clean up
                        this.subs.push(selfDeleteSub);
                        /*************************************************************************************/
                    }


                },
                error=>{
                    console.log(error);
                }
            );
        }



    }


mandar_mensaje(datos){
    let chat:ChatService;
/*This service is used to save the data that arrives from the socket*/
   this._chatService.sendMessage(datos.id_user_to,datos.id_user_from,datos.mensaje).subscribe(
        response=>{


        },
        error=>{
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
/*Here you should check if there is the user id box that comes from the socket and if there is updating the messages that are being displayed in the view*/
}



}
```

App.component.html(this is where the user list is)

```
<div class="sidenav">
  <ul style="padding: 0!important;">
    <li *ngFor="let persona of personas">
    <div style="padding:  5px !important;padding-bottom:  10px !important;position: relative;">
      <div *ngIf="persona.foto_perfil!='';else foto_default">
        <img class="foto_perfil_ejecutivo" src="{{url_base_perfil}}{{persona.foto_perfil}}" alt="">
        <a class="nombre_ejecutivo" id="{{persona.id}}" [attr.data-nombre]="persona.nombre"[attr.data-foto_perfil]="persona.foto_perfil"(click)="onClickAdd($event.target)">{{persona.nombre}}</a>
      </div>
      <ng-template #foto_default>
        <img class="foto_perfil_ejecutivo" src="{{url_foto_perfil_default}}" alt="">
        <a class="nombre_ejecutivo" id="{{persona.id}}" [attr.data-nombre]="persona.nombre"[attr.data-foto_perfil]="persona.foto_perfil"(click)="onClickAdd($event.target)">{{persona.nombre}}</a>
      </ng-template>

    </div>

    </li>

  </ul>

</div>


<ng-template #componentsContainer></ng-template>
```

conversacion.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter,ViewChild,ElementRef,ComponentRef,Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import {Mensaje} from "../../models/mensaje";
import {ChatService} from "../../services/chat.service";
import {Global} from "../../services/global";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-conversacion',
    templateUrl: './conversacion.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./conversacion.component.css'],
    providers:[ChatService]
})
export class ConversacionComponent implements OnInit {

    @Output() deleteSelf = new EventEmitter<number>();
    @Input() numberCreated: number;
    @Input() mensajes:Mensaje[];/*este es el que uso*/
    @Input() id_persona_destino:number;
    @Input() nombre_persona_destino:string;
    @Input() foto_persona_destino:string;
    public url_base_perfil=Global.url_base_perfil;
    public url_foto_perfil_default=Global.url_foto_perfil_default;
    user = 1;
    public ultimomensaje:Mensaje;
    scrolltop:number = null;
    constructor(private  _chatService:ChatService,private renderer: Renderer2) {}

    ngOnInit() {

    }
    sendMessage(message,element)
    {
        let destino = element.getAttribute('data-destino');

        const nd = new Date;
        const data = {
            message ,
            userId : this.user,
            time : nd.getHours() + ":" + nd.getMinutes()
        };

            this._chatService.sendMessage(1,destino,message).subscribe(
                response=>{
                    this._chatService.getLastMessage(1,destino).subscribe(
                        response=>{
                            if(response.mensaje){
                                this.mensajes=[...this.mensajes,response.mensaje];
                            }

                        },
                        error=>{
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    );

            },
            error=>{
                console.log(error);
            }
        );

    }

    autoResize(e) {
        var ele = e.target;
        var t = ele.scrollTop;
        ele.scrollTop = 0

        if (t > 0) {
            //ele.style.overflowY = "hidden";
            ele.style.height = (ele.offsetHeight + t + t) + "px";
        }


    }

}
```

conversacion.component.html(this is the chat box)

```
<div style="display: inline-flex;">

    <div id="sidebar_secondary" class="tabbed_sidebar ng-scope chat_sidebar">
            <div class="popup-head">
                <div class="popup-head-left pull-left">
                    <a title="Gurdeep Osahan (Web Designer)" target="_blank">
                        <div href="#"*ngIf="foto_persona_destino!='';else foto_default">
                            <img class="md-user-image" alt="" title="" src="{{url_base_perfil}}{{foto_persona_destino}}" title="Gurdeep Osahan (Web Designer)" alt="Gurdeep Osahan (Web Designer)">
                            <h1>{{nombre_persona_destino}}</h1>
                        </div>
                    <ng-template #foto_default>
                        <img class="md-user-image" alt="" title="" src="{{url_foto_perfil_default}}" title="Gurdeep Osahan (Web Designer)" alt="Gurdeep Osahan (Web Designer)">
                        <h1>{{nombre_persona_destino}}</h1>
                    </ng-template>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="popup-head-right pull-right">
                    <button (click)="deleteSelf.emit(id_persona_destino)" data-widget="remove" id="removeClass" class="chat-header-button pull-right" type="button"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="chat" class="conversation chat_box_wrapper chat_box_small chat_box_active" style="opacity: 1; display: block; transform: translateX(0px);" #scrollMe [scrollTop]="scrollMe.scrollHeight">

                <div class="chat_box touchscroll chat_box_colors_a">

                    <div class="chat_message_wrapper"[ngClass]="{'chat_message_right': message.id_user_from == user , 'otro': message.id_user_from != user }" *ngFor="let message of mensajes">
                        <div class="chat_user_avatar">
                            <a href="#" target="_blank" *ngIf="message.id_user_from != user" >
                                <div href="#"*ngIf="foto_persona_destino!='';else foto_default_conversacion">
                                    <img alt="" title="" src="{{url_base_perfil}}{{foto_persona_destino}}" class="md-user-image">
                                </div>
                                <ng-template #foto_default_conversacion>
                                    <img alt="" title="" src="{{url_foto_perfil_default}}" class="md-user-image">
                                </ng-template>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="chat_message">
                            <li>
                                <p>
                                    {{ message.contenido }}
                                    <span class="chat_message_time">{{ message.fecha }}</span>
                                </p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
            <div class="text-bar">
                    <textarea style="width: 100% !important;" type="text" [attr.data-destino]="id_persona_destino" #msgInput (keydown)="autoResize($event)" (keydown.enter)="sendMessage(msgInput.value,msgInput);false;msgInput.value='';" placeholder=""></textarea>

            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try to maintain a field in the `conversacion.component` whether component is active or not?

Comment: I do not understand what you say. Could you show me from my example how would you do that?

Comment: Added answer with steps. See if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain a field named `isActive` in the `ConversacionComponent` and set it to false by default.

```
export class ConversacionComponent implements OnInit {
   ...
   @Input() isActive = false;
   ...
```

first time OR when showing the chat window, update `isActive` field to `true` using component instance inside `onClickAdd` function.

When you get the response in your `ChartService`, first check for `isActive` field is true or not and then load the messages.

When user closes the chat window, on that event set `isActive` to `false`.

Note: This is one approach to know whether component is active or not.

Comment: I need to check if the component is active or not in the mandar_mensaje () function that runs inside the OnInit (). The issue is that I don't know how to get the exact instance of all the components and do the verification you say in that function. For example if there are 2 chat windows open at the moment a message arrives I need to know exactly if any of those 2 windows that are being displayed is where I should update the messages(that is ... what is the component where I should do that verification)

Comment: I see `this.alreadyDone` array holds element id's (i believe it is the unique id for each user). You could try to hold component instance or `ComponentRef` in a map with user id as key. 
When message comes for that user id, you can check in the map and get the component instance and check whether it's active or not and update message accordingly.

Comment: Sorry if I do not understand much, because I have been very short with angular. this.alreadyDone effectively saves the users id. I understand the logic of what you want me to do but I don't know how to code that. Could you help me if it doesn't bother you?

Comment: @Jesús Soto Mitjans Can you setup stackblitz for your code? - Atleast, I can add changes what i explained earlier.

Comment: Here I send you the project link a little more outdated at the visual level.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ucnueu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Could you access to the link well?

Comment: Here's fork of your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mwe7uu?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

I added approach and added comments wherever required.
I did not have full context and chat service didn't have response types. So, could not add full code and test it. Added basic changes of the approach.

Hope it helps

Comment: I modify my stackblitz with your updated code and modify in the app.component.ts the part where you receive the service data. With your code I already get the service reference well and I can add the message that you send me from the external app .. .but even the chat window is not updated with that last message. I think something is missing. I left you a comment on that function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203254/discussion-between-ppgowda4-and-jesus-soto-mitjans).

Comment: I was storing `ComponentRef` in the map. You need to get instance first before updating the message

if(response.mensajes) {
 this.compInstances[datos.id_user_from].instance.mensajes=response.mensajes;
}